# Plot a huge number of points with Leaflet.Photo

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I want to make a leaflet map with photo geotagged photos instead of marker symbols. The plugin Leaflet.Photo provides exactly what I need. In the future it is planned to represent up to 30.000 geotagged  photos on the map, visualized with the built in marker cluster method of Leaflet.Photo. Since I do not have such a huge collection of geotagged photos yet, my question is, if this is realistic performance wise. Is there a chance that such a huge number of photos can still be loaded on the map and not crash the browser?

Comment: Are you planning to show all 30.000 photos at once? If not, where is the problem?

Comment: No, the plan is to use the marker.cluster plugin. I could imagine it consumes a lot of time to cluster the points. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Clustering won't be a problem, more likely download of 30.000 points and properties for markers if there's to much of data.

Comment: I think trying to show 30 000 photos at once may cause an issue. You could use the MarkerCluster at certain zoom levels and then turn on the photos once an appropriate zoom level is reached. In terms of performance I would guess it has to do with how you will be loading the photos into the Leaflet map.